# How do I resolve the error "The resource mydb1 for service type RDS is not authorized for this account" with aws pi command

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, database-performance

I have Admin access with my default AWS profile.  I am using the latest version of AWS CLI module and it is version 2.13.36.  When I run the following CLI command:

```
aws pi list-performance-analysis-reports --service-type RDS --identifier "mydb1"
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the ListPerformanceAnalysisReports operation: The resource mydb1 for service type RDS is not authorized for this account
```

I am not sure what more access would I give myself.  Does anyone have any success with "aws pi" command?

I was also trying to create a report via Performance Insights dashboard but I do not see a way to save it to a report.  I can access the Performance Insights and interact with the graph, but don't see a way to save it to a report.

Comment: Maybe you can run `aws sts get-caller-identity` to verify the IAM identity used to authenticate the request when making calls to aws services.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitJain, it is using the same identity as I expect, i.e. the same identity through which I access the AWS console.  I did hear back from AWS, it turns out that this feature (reporting) is only available with the paid Performance Insights tier and not with the free tier which is what I was using.  I am going to verify it soon and will post back my findings.

Comment: Got more clarification from AWS.  This feature is called "Analyzing database performance for a period of time" and according to this page, it is only supported for RDS/PostgreSQL.  I was trying to do it on RDS/MSSQL.  Hope this helps anyone else trying to do the same.

Comment: You can post it as answer:) so it can others also.

Answer (score 0):

This particular feature is called [Analyzing database performance for a period of time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.AnalyzePerformanceTimePeriod.html) and most of AWS documentation about how to create a Performance Insight Report for a time period don't clarify that this particular feature is only supported on RDS for PostgreSQL db engine. It was only clear after contacting AWS Technical Documentation team and they directed me to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Overview.Engines.html) which lists the supported DB engines for this feature.

Hopefully, others that are in my boat might find this useful.